# How to set equal to nan after first grouping of values above threshold in numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If I have a numpy array like this:

```
 np.array([-9, -8, -9, -7, -7, -4, -4, -2, -3, -4, -4, -8, -4, -2, -8, -2])
```

and a threshold of -4

How do I find the first grouping of values greater than -5 and then set all values after that first grouping equal to np.nan such that I get an array like this:

```
 np.array([-9, -8, -9, -7, -7, -4, -4, -2, -3, -4, -4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array taking it 5 at a time, i.e. considering i to i+5 for every i. Check each for your condition(in loop or through method call) and if its false move to next set. Once its true, break the loop and record the value of i at which the grouping ends. Take i+1 as starting index for a new loop and then set i+1 to end of array to nan.

Comment: Just wanted to say that if the array is really long, this approach would not be time efficient. Instead you could use preprocessing to speed this up.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the assigment of `Nan` so I used zero. If the array is large try something like this without for-loop. The solution depends on the variability of the input array, so check wether it should be `<`, `>` or rather `>=`, `<=` .  Can this give an idea (?):

**update**: due to the comments here an improved suggestion:

```
A = np.array([-9, -8, -9, -7, -7, -4, -4, -2, -3, -4, -4, -8, -4, -2, -8, -2])

val = -5 

ind1 = (A > val).argmax()
ind2 = (A[ind1:]<val).argmax()
A[ind1+ind2:]  = 0
A

array([-9, -8, -9, -7, -7, -4, -4, -2, -3, -4, -4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

Comment: This is the incorrect output.  He wants to find the first *group* of values that are greater than his threshold (the first group continues to the `-4` before the `-8`)

Comment: @ user3483203 : Sure ? Look at the output in the question !

Comment: I am looking at the output in the question.  You `0` out the `-2 -3, -4, -4` while it is in his output..

Comment: ok, I agree, I obviously did not look carefully enogh at the -4 , -4 sequence